# getDefaultProcessEngine() return null

Tags: java, activiti

`ProcessEngines.getDefaultProcessEngine()` 
return me null when I try init a new process in activiti engine.

Do you know what could be the reason ?

Answer (score 2):

Taken from the Activi forums user frederikheremans:

> As stated in the Javadoc for ProcessEngines, this class is used by a
>   ServletContextListener, which calls the ProcessEngines.init().  The
>   init() will scan the classpath for activiti.properties an tries to
>   build a ProcessEngine for each file found.
>
> The getDefaultProcessEngine() only works [if] the ProcessEngines.init()
>   has been called (by
>   org.activiti.impl.servlet.listener.ProcessEnginesServletContextListener
>   or by calling it yourself once) and if a process-engine with name
>   'default' is available.

The OP of the thread I got that from stated that he too received **null** from getDefaultProcessEngine. Hope that helps.